# How do I support different phone and screen sizes for background images that are relative to multiple layout Objects

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, background-image

So right now one of my layouts has a table image set as a background then I have TextView objects line up with the corresponding cells in the table that is my background. 
(I basically use spaces and padding to manipulate the TextView strings)

I test using an emulator and my Droid X and I notice that the background shifts sizes to fit the screen.  Thats great and all, but makes it impossible to line up my TextView strings correctly to match the different screen sizes. 
(It can work on one, but not the other)

My questions to possible solutions:

- Can I make this process more generic to fit different screen sizes?
- Is there a way to keep the image in my background the same size no matter what device it is  running on and have the empty spaces it doesn't fill be black?
- Is there a way to easily create a table in android with color filled cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest cutting up the background into several images, and then having the image that is meant to line up with the `TextView`, the background of the `TextView`. Just my 2c.

Comment: ok i actually figured it out but I'm having one problem that I just cant seem to figure out. I have a list of buttons.  In eclipse they fit where I want them too and there is almost no space between them, but when I test it the buttons get a very small 1cm space between them and it throws everything off.  Do buttons add space between each other if they are too close when you test?

Comment: The Buttons should not be adding space, but perhaps the Layout you are using is. In either case, check the padding and margin properties.